# raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, gpu

I Try to install Pytorch on my Windows 10 system.
I wanna Use a anaconda env.
i followed the instruction 'https://pytorch.org/' stable 1.12.1 && Conda && Python && cuda 11.6
(conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.6 -c pytorch -c conda-forge)

Before I installed conda 11.6, when i enter nvcc --version in the console i get the output  :

*NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Mar__8_18:36:24_Pacific_Standard_Time_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.124
Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.31057947_0*

I also installed conda forge following this instruction https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html

but now, if i try to run **print(torch.cuda.is_available())** 'false' is outprinted

If i run *conda list* i get this (just some):

pytorch                   1.10.2              py3.9_cpu_0    pytorch

pytorch                   1.10.2              py3.9_cpu_0    pytorch

torchaudio                0.10.2                 py39_cpu  [cpuonly]  pytorch

torchvision               0.11.3                 py39_cpu  [cpuonly]  pytorch

My GPU is an RTX 2070 Super. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1):

In my case i try to change the environment so i create new environment using conda then i download pytorch again from pytorch.org the compatible version for my GPU and then i tap the cmd of training and it works. hope it helps you